# AppSrv01 doesnt have write permission

Tags: eclipse, command-line, websphere, rad

i know that the default profile name when i installed websphere was Appsrv01, I want to create my own AppSrv02 but the location of my IBM Websphere was in C: and i dont have any write permission, i dont have any admin rights also..

[image: Image Here]

using **COMMAND-LINE**, I want to make my profile folder to be writable, so that my newly created AppSrv02 will be list down in the profile names in my RAD.

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Can you describe a little bit more your environment. Where is WAS installed? What's the WAS location you have configured in your RAD? What versions of WAS and RAD are you using? Are you using WAS standalone or ND?

Please, add as much details as possible. RAD typically detects the WAS servers installed along with it and can also detect whether a profile exists or it needs to create one.

Comment: Hi Victor, WAS installed at C:\\ , most likely i configured it where the WAS installed, WAS version is 8.5.5.7 and RAD 9.0... WAS standalone,,, well the profile exists. the default name was AppSrv01, but RAD can't find it at the list because AppSrv01 is NOT writable... AND ALSO. I dont have any admin rights.. so i cant "Run As Administrator" in my RAD..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that's your problem. In order to have a usable profile in WAS, your user must have write permissions. See this link from WAS ND infocenter, it applies to WAS standalone too.

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.installation.nd.doc/ae/tpro_manage_nonroot.html

If you cannot change the write permissions to this profile, you'll need to create your own. For this, you can either use WAS Profile Management Tool, WAS CLI or you can create your profile using the *Configure profiles...* link in the WAS server creation wizard you posted. I'd use the RAD way because RAD validates, within the IDE, the proper permissions that you need to create and use the profile within RAD.

Comment: Thanks Victor Sosa :D

Comment: removing the write protection from the file system on the AppServ01 folder fixed this for me.

Answer (score 0):

First check whether you have admin rights or not if your using User/Guest profile, by creating any new folder in C drive where IBM WAS is installed.

If you have Admin rights, than right click on RAD run as administrator. It should work fine.

If Profile doesnt show up in drop down, Configure new profile and try checking that way.

If you dont have Admin rights better install RAD in any local drive other than C

Answer (score 0):

Running Eclipse with Admin rights and removing the read-only tick for the AppServXX folder/WAS folder couldn't help me... cause I copied the WAS server from another PC :). So for those of you who want to move / migrate your development environment:

I did a search inside the copied WAS, Eclipse and the project's workspace folder for their old paths (with Total Commander, feed the results into a list) and dragged all the files (except the log ones) into my editor (NotePad++) and did a replace in all open documents for the new paths. It's a bit lucrative, but it took only 10 minutes for me and afterwards the WAS server in Eclipse showed the correct profile and it also did start up well.